# Htaccess обработка всех запросов кроме файлов

Tags: php, .htaccess

**.htaccess** имеет такое правило:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

В роутере есть такое правило:
`'(.+?)/?$' => ['controller' => 'category'],`

При открытии абсолютно любой странице, срабатывает контроллер CategoryController.php. Долго помучаться пришлось, оказывается все подключаемые скрипты и стили вызывают этот контроллер, тем самым выполняються лишние запросы в БД.

Собственно вопрос: как исправить или какое правило добавить, что бы htaccess не брал во внимание пути к файлам заканчивающиеся на .css, .js, .png и т.д., которых может быть много?

Comment: Может быть, вам просто следует отредактировать регулярные выражения, чтобы исключить упомянутые типы файлов?

Comment: @GreatTech Спасибо, помогло, только минус зачем было ставить. Раз я задал вопрос, значит я не знаю ответа на него. Другое дело если бы вопрос был глупым, тогда я согласился бы с Вашим минусом. Спасибо.

Comment: Я подумал, может только для меня ответ казался достаточно простым. Убрал минус.

Comment: @GreatTech на свежий взгляд всегда можно быстрее увидеть ошибку. Спасибо.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` обычно пишут перед тем как в индекс.пхп перенаправлять в таких случаях

Comment: @teran это написано было. Я же не буду весь код сюда переписывать. Спасибо.

Comment: и действительно,  давайте код половинками выкладывать. Если бы сие было написано, то реальные png-jpg-css файлы в контроллер бы не отправлялись.